# Question on term used for this kind of questionnaire item and type of analysis followed

Tags: survey, scales

I have a question on the term used for the type of the item that I would like to use and how it is "usually" analysed.

Let's assume that we have two items and the one is linked to the other, namely, the one is the answer in a multiple choice question and the second on quantifies an attribute, for example, "did you find the lesson interesting" then a LIKERT scale is provided and then another item that asks whether finding the lesson interesting was important for the respondent (something like classification/prioritization). So an item attaches somehow an additional quantity to the first one. These kinds of "pair of items" are used in customer satisfaction research usually ...

Do you know how they are called?
How are they analysed?
Would Kullback-Leibler divergence be needed?